# What can be done about repetitive posting of homework questions?

Tags: discussion, homework-dump

There has been a number of repetitive postings of what seems to be unedited homework questions ("what is the best technique to..."), apparently from first-time users probably going through some kind of programming course. The comments given seem to be completely ignored. What can be done about this phenomenon?

Comment: FWIW, I believe that it has been separate individuals posting the duplicate questions. I do not believe that it was a single individual.

Comment: It was identical text, apparently copied and pasted, without any further text communicating what the user had already tried. If it's actually different users, somebody seems to have told them that copying and pasting the question to stack exchange is a good way of getting an answer.

Comment: agreed. The three Q's that I saw were virtually identical. One of the comments on one of those Q's implied it was the same person behind all of the questions. My investigation of the Q's suggested it was three people

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm not sure that anything special is needed.

If the question is not a good fit for our site, vote to close. Optionally, leave a comment with guidance on how the question can be improved (or up vote an existing comment, if one exists). Also, you can consider down voting the question. If the question is already closed and the author shows no signs of improving it, votes to delete can be casted.

The system already has question blocks in place that can be triggered by sufficient negative scoring on questions, closed questions, and deleted questions. If the user doesn't make an attempt to understand how things work, this will kick in and prevent the user from posting new questions while giving them an appropriate chance to understand what is expected.

I would recommend avoid using the flag for moderator attention on these unless they require fast moderator action to close and/or delete. Putting them into a queue should be sufficient, and also after a few down votes, they fall off the front page and aren't visible unless someone is looking for them.